# could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (3) while using timestamp to build neural network in python

Tags: python, neural-network

Here I want predict value every 60 minutes. So I have data 540 with three inputs. so I wrote an code with time steps and it gave me this error. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

my code :

```
y=data['y1'].astype(int)
cols=['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
x=data[cols].astype(int)
n = x.shape[0]
p = x.shape[1]
x  = x.values
y = y.values
train_start = 0
train_end = int(np.floor(0.8*n))
test_start = train_end+1 
test_end = n
x_train = x[np.arange(train_start, train_end), :]
x_test = x[np.arange(test_start, test_end), :]
y_train = y[np.arange(train_start, train_end), :]
y_test = y[np.arange(test_start, test_end), :]
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

num_time_steps = 9
num_features = x.shape[1]

x_train = np.zeros((x_train.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")
x_test = np.zeros((x_test.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")

for i in range(len(x_train)):
for timestep in range(num_time_steps):
    x_train[i][timestep] = x_train[i + timestep]

for i in range(len(x_test)):
for timestep in range(num_time_steps):
    x_test[i][timestep] = x_test[i + timestep]

 y_train = y_train[num_time_steps - 1:]
 y_test = y_test[num_time_steps - 1:]
```

[image]

[image]

change code:

```
train_end = 80
x_train=x[0: train_end ,]
x_test=x[train_end +1: ,]
y_train=y[0: train_end]
y_test=y[train_end +1:] 
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))
num_time_steps = 9
num_features = x.shape[1]
x_train_n = np.zeros((x_train.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")
x_test_n = np.zeros((x_test.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")
for i in range(len(x_train_n)):
for timestep in range(num_time_steps):
    x_train_n[i][timestep] = x_train[i + timestep]
for i in range(len(x_test_n)):
for timestep in range(num_time_steps):
    x_test_n[i][timestep] = x_test[i+timestep]
y_train_n = y_train[num_time_steps - 1:]
y_test_n = y_test[num_time_steps - 1:]
```

Error,
[image]

Comment: can you share the exception message, and the line which error occurs?

Comment: @gunes I paste the image , that is showing the error that is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use separate variables for the 3D and 2D `x_train`s:

```
x_train_n = np.zeros((x_train.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")
x_test_n = np.zeros((x_test.shape[0] - num_time_steps + 1, num_time_steps, num_features), dtype="float32")
```

And, your outer loop should span the *new* `x_train`, i.e. `x_train_n`:

```
for i in range(len(x_train_n)):
   for timestep in range(num_time_steps):
       x_train_n[i][timestep] = x_train[i + timestep].squeeze()
```

Change the other loop (the one for the test case) as well.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply . I changed the code according to your code and it gives me this error "too many indices for array" Here I paaste the image of the error. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: That’s another error. $y$ seems to be 1D. Remove the second index with semicolon.

Comment: Yes I changed my code as you mentioned. Then it gave me this error,"could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)" Can you please help me to solve this problem? Here I paste the image of the error and change code.

Comment: I've updated the answer with `squeeze` command.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you explain me why  we put squeeze?

Comment: it removes the dimensions with 1, e.g. (5,1) to (5); or (4,1,5) to (4,5) etc. The error states that we're trying to equate a np array of dimension (3,1) to another with dimension (3).

Comment: Okay I got it. Thank you for helping me to solve this problem.